# How to add a dictionary within firebase friendly data structure

Tags: ios, dictionary, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get my data ready to update my firebase database,
the problem is that I don't know how to insert a dictionary within a "firebase friendly" data structure.

My aproach:

```
class func updateGroup(group: Group){
   let ref = Database.database().reference().child("groups")
   let groupValues = ["description": group.description,
                      "name": group.name,
                       "users": group.users]
   let childUpdates = [group.id! : groupValues]
   ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
 }
```

`name` and `description` properties are `String` while users is a `[String: String]` dictionary:

```
class Group{
    public var name: String?
    public var description: String?
    public var id: String?
    public var users: [String: String]?
    ...
}
```

What is the proper way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define the `dictionary` as `[String: Any]` since it has another `dictionary` within it.

```
let groupValues = ["description": group.description,
                   "name": group.name,
                   "users": group.users] as [String: Any]
```